# How can I pass variable from one class to another in Python

Tags: python

There is an code example

```
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):   
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        sld = wx.Slider(pnl, value=0, minValue=0, maxValue=200, pos=(30, 20), 
            size=(650, 15), style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)
        sld1 = wx.Slider(pnl, value=0, minValue=0, maxValue=360, pos=(30, 50), 
            size=(650, 15), style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)

        sld.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)
        sld1.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)

        self.txt1 = wx.StaticText(pnl, label='0', pos=(250, 120))
        self.txt2 = wx.StaticText(pnl, label='0', pos=(10, 50))

        self.SetSize((700, 200))
        self.SetTitle('ROBO ARM')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)    

    def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
        id_slider = e.GetId()
        obj = e.GetEventObject()
        VARIABLE = obj.GetValue()
        tty = str(val)+str(id_slider)
        self.txt1.SetLabel(str(VARIABLE)


class Example1(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example1, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(350, 280))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#d4d4d4'))

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#c56c00'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 7, 90, **VARIABLE NEEDS HERE**)
```

I have a two questions: how pass VARIABLE from Class Example to Example1 to the marked place
and second is as I understood I can change self in this line:self.txt1.SetLabel(str(VARIABLE) to something like Example.InitUI (and something else here) - can u write this string as it must be?

thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you want. Mind posting a [mcve]?

Comment: Two questions how pass and additional second to understanding - that's all

Comment: Do you have instances of those classes? The instances can communicate if one has a reference to the other. Then you can implement a method or something to set the value of the variable. For example in `Example` you may have a code doing `example1_instance.set_the_variable(VARIABLE)`, or in `Example1` you may have a code doing `VARIABLE=example_instance.get_the_variable()`. Otherwise you may put that VARIABLE in the class, before method definitions, and refer to it as `Example.VARIABLE`, but it would be orrible...

Comment: Okay it's sounds nice, but can you please show me in code what need to write in dc.DrawRectangle(10, 7, 90, **VARIABLE NEEDS HERE**)

Comment: in that line of code you need to write one of the last 2 example I already did, or `VARIABLE` and the first example I already did.

Comment: does not work. invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this scenario (`VARIABLE` seems to be a shared state for all instances of `Example1`) it looks appropriate to use a global variable.

```
VARIABLE = None

class Example(wx.Frame):
    ...

    def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
        global VARIABLE

        id_slider = e.GetId()
        obj = e.GetEventObject()
        VARIABLE = obj.GetValue()
        tty = str(val)+str(id_slider)
        self.txt1.SetLabel(str(VARIABLE))


class Example1(wx.Frame):
    ...

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        global VARIABLE

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#d4d4d4'))

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#c56c00'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 7, 90, VARIABLE)
```

or, if by some reason you want to avoid globals, you can use a class variable (still assuming it is shared across all instances of `Example1`:

```
class Example(wx.Frame):
    ...

    def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
        id_slider = e.GetId()
        obj = e.GetEventObject()
        VARIABLE = obj.GetValue()
        tty = str(val)+str(id_slider)
        self.txt1.SetLabel(str(VARIABLE))
        Example1.VARIABLE = VARIABLE


class Example1(wx.Frame):
    ...

    def OnPaint(self, e):    
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#d4d4d4'))

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#c56c00'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 7, 90, Example1.VARIABLE)
```

Comment: VARIABLE calls in every class every time in a new way again? Do not know it, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Глобальную переменную в каждом классе надо заново вызывать - этого я не знал

Comment: yes, you need to declare a variable as global in every scope. So, even if you access the same global from two methods of the same class you need to declare the variable as global in both methods

Comment: Thanks, clear. Method with Example1.VARIABLE = VARIABLE does't work AttributeError: type object 'Example1' has no attribute when I try to print it

Comment: It works in my console, but I inherit from `object`... it might be because `wx.Frame` is an old-style class